# SharePoint search timer jobs missing. How to get them back

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, timer-jobs, sharepoint-search

Some of the timer jobs related to search are missing and trying to figure out how to bring them back. Below is list of missing timer jobs from SharePoint 2013 farm. I have already tried, $ssa.refreshcomponenets & $ssa.Provision() with no luck. Any help will be appreciated.

Analytics Timer Job for Search Service Application

Crawl Log Cleanup for Search Application

Rebalance crawl store partitions

Search Custom Dictionaries

Query Classification Dictionary Update for Search Application

Rebalance crawl store partitions for

Search Custom Dictionaries

Spelling Customizations Upgrade

Spelling Dictionary Update

Usage Analytics Timer Job for Search Application

Btw, same question was posted [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/531350/sharepoint-2013-search-service-overall-state-degra.html) but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run SharePoint 2013 Products Configuration Wizard?

You could run the SharePoint products configuration wizard twice to get timer jobs back. First time select disconnect from this server farm. Second time connect your sever with the configuration database.
For Reference: [Restore Workflow Timer Job](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/forefront/en-US/e79cec3b-cf90-4c42-ad17-50ea82f26be5/restore-workflow-timer-job?forum=sharepointgeneral)

And did you try to run EnsureDefaultJobs on the farm?

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm

$farm.TimerService.EnsureDefaultJobs()
```

More detials: [App Installation Service Timer Job Missing](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144517/app-installation-service-timer-job-missing/144673)

Comment: Hi Casey, Thanks for the reply, I tried to run PSconfig on all server few times and also clear config cache but no luck. These jobs are still missing. I have not remove and add the server from the farm yet but you can see at the link ist preetty complex topology so i will leave removing and adding to the farm as a last resort.. I have also tried EnsureDefaultJobs) method but I assume its only for administrative timer jobs it did not do any thing for search related timer jobs.